# Copy column from one database to another and insert data depends on condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two databases on the same SQL server. The first is named Aa with a table Models in which there are two columns: Id and Desc and Bb database with a table ListOfModels in which there are three columns: Id, MachineTypeId, ModelName. I need to copy all Desc values from Aa database into ModelName in Bb and insert 1 into MachineTypeId if Desc starts with "K", otherwise insert 2.

Can you please help me write the script for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is unclear as to whether you want to insert new rows into the table or just update matching values.

If you actually want to insert records:

```
insert into bb..ListOfModels(MachineTypeId, ModelName)
    select (case when TypeId like 'K%' then 1 else 2 end), m.[desc]
    from aa..Models m;
```

If you want to update the records based on matching by `id`:

```
update lom
    set ModelName = [desc],
        MachineTypeId = (case when m.TypeId like 'K%' then 1 else 2 end)
    from bb..ListOfModels lom join
         aa..Models m 
         on lom.id = m.id;
```

By the way, `desc` is a lousy name for a column, because it is a reserved word in SQL.

Comment: Thanks, thats works well. And what if the database that I want to insert data into is on another SQL server? I guess I should change the last statement 'from aa..Models m;' somehow.

Comment: @user2925794 . . . You need four part naming if the tables are on databases on different servers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

```
Case Substr(MachineTypeID,1,1) When "K" Then 1 Else 2 End
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot the End :)